# Changing Capitalization of range in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to get all unique values in a range.
I am running into the problem when using this it spits out many wrong values.

Example:

Range:

```
Apple
Dog
Cat
apple
Cat
Dog
```

=Unique() would output Apple and apple.

How do I select those individually?
Essentially, what I am trying to do is make them all the same caps like IgnoreCase. I tried lower(), but that just outputs one value.

Comment: In Excel of works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRFeV.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(LOWER(A1:A)))
```

Comment: Can you tell me why this works, but using { } to formulate an array does not ?

Comment: I can only tell you that this is what `ARRAYFORMULA` do.

Comment: @ColinKoenig using { } to formulate an array *does* work to make an array.  But you need ARRAYFORMULA() to APPLY functions to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(A1:A; "select lower(A)"))
```

or

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(LOWER(A1:A)))
```